# Add SSD to iMac: Thunderbolt or internal?

Tags: imac, ssd, thunderbolt

Is there any thunderbolt SSD which can be as fast or at least not much slower than [internal one from OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Mercury_6G)? I want to use is as system disk. It will be good to have two thunderbolt ports on this thing to daisy chain display.

It will be also a big bonus if I can buy it in Europe (because of specifics of organization where I am working).

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbolt is 10 Gb/s. Internal ones use SATA II or III at 3 or 6 Gb/s, respectively.

However the Thunderbolt ones use SATA III internally. So you won't see any difference.